# jquery- moving bux in x axis when shift button is pressed while draging

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I create fiddle for this code
the problem is I have no idea how I can make a div move in x axis when shift is pressed.

Please, look here: https://jsfiddle.net/seotesting24/wqL6kzfL/

**JS**:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    $('div').mousedown(function () {
        var dragElement = $(this);

        $(document).mousemove(function (e) {
            var elementWidth = dragElement.width() / 2;
            var elementHeight = dragElement.height() / 2;

            var x = e.pageX - elementHeight;
            var y = e.pageY - elementWidth;
            dragElement.css({top: y + 'px', left: x + 'px', backgroundColor: 'red'});

            $(document).on('keydown',function(e){
                if(e.which == 16){

                }

            });

        });
        $('div').mouseup(function () {
            $(document).unbind('mousemove');
            dragElement.css({backgroundColor:'gray'})
        })
    });

});
```

**HTML**:

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

**CSS**:

```
    div {
        position: absolute;
        width: 140px;
        height: 140px;
        background-color: gray;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }

    div:hover, div:active {
        cursor: move;
    }
```

Comment: So you mean the darg and drop  functionality is correct but you want it to move only when shift is pressed? is that it?

Comment: @AnujaAgarwal Yes. I just want to seem my element move in x axis as user pushes shift and move the mouse But without that, drag and drop should be normally done